# How to report a bug of default "Document Viewer" in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, default-programs

I have been using a default "Document Viewer" in ubuntu heavily in last 2-3 weeks. I have noticed an irregular behaviour while adding a bookmark of particular type.

I am pretty new to ubuntu community and don't know how to report a bug.
So, can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default *Document Viewer* in Ubuntu is evince. Therefore

```
ubuntu-bug evince
```

You should see something like this

[image]

Click on <kbd>Send</kbd> and a browser window opens. Login and report your bug

[image]